# How to evaluate "Node Address" in NiFi RouteOnAttribute

Tags: apache-nifi

One of our 3 nifi nodes are causing problems and I've got a large backlog of flow files sitting on that node, blocking the other nodes flow files now as well.

I would like to be able to split off the node 3 flow files so that node 1 and 2 flow files can continue to be processed. I was hoping there's a way to use a RouteOnAttribute processor to evaluate the node address of the flow file but I can't seem to find the correct attribute.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: not sure but did you try these attributes - `${hostname()} or ${nodeAddress}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these attributes - ${hostname()} or ${nodeAddress}